# Simple app with SimpleAddapter doesnt work?

Tags: java, android

My simple-app doesnt work with this line:

```
lsview.setAdapter(listadapter);
```

But in log no message about errors. Without this line it's working. And if i using ArrrayAdapter for my ListView it work. I dont know what it is! When I using debbuger, my app crashing in Looper.java. But in log no message about it.

Code:

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    public int [] val=new int[]{41,24,78,12,56,92};
    public ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> listval;
    public Map<String,Object> maplist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listval=new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(val.length);
        for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
            maplist=new HashMap<String,Object>();
            maplist.put("ll",val[i]);
            maplist.put("pb", val[i]);
            maplist.put("Text", "Day " + i + ": " + val[i] + "%");
            listval.add(maplist);
        }
        String from[]=new String[]{"ll","pb","Text"};
        int[] to=new int[]{R.id.llLoad,R.id.pbLoad,R.id.tvLoad};
        SimpleAdapter listadapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,listval,R.layout.item,from,to);
        //listadapter.setViewBinder(new MySimpleViewBinder());
        ListView lsview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
       lsview.setAdapter(listadapter);
    }

}
```

Help pls.

Comment: I just used your code and it ran well, see http://postimg.org/image/lk242gke7/ you must have a problem in your layouts, could you paste the content of your activity_main.xml and your item.xml layouts please?

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you are having in the `String[]` the same keys in order to get the Values will not work by itself. Replace this:

```
String from[]=new String[]{"ll","pb","Text"};
```

with this:

```
String from[]=new String[]{maplist.get("ll").toString(),maplist.get("pb").toString(),maplist.get("Text").toString()};
```

You have to get the value based on the key in the `HashMap`.
hope it helps!!!

Comment: No ;( Its not work. App crashing in Looper.java. Log is clear, i dont know what is it.

Comment: what do you mean its not working? and what is Looper.java

Comment: App crashing. Looper.java - i dont know what is it, i think it somethink from android core.